# Recalculate center math question

Tags: javascript, math

Want to recalculate x and y in a **centered layout** relative to the current viewers resolution.

I have two numbers a set of coordinates x and y.

```
x=140
y=80
```

x and y was recorded in a resolution sessionWidth, sessionHeight

```
sessionWidth = 1024
sessionHeight = 400
```

Want to recalculate x and y so that they are relative to the viewers resolution.

```
currentViewWidth = 1280
currentViewHeight = 500
```

So want to plot x,y for a lot of coordinates (with different sessionWidth and SessionHeight) but want to normalize to the currentViewWidth and currentViewHeight.

currentViewWidth and currentViewHeight are constant.

How on earth do I do that - do you got a formula I can use?
Thanks a million.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
newX = currentViewWidth * x / sessionViewWidth
newY = currentViewHeight * y / sesionViewHeight
```

Answer (score 0):

new_x = 140/1024*1280 = 175
new_y = 80/400*500 = 100